# Dictionary access is stopping the code flow

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a 3 seperate dictionaries that I manually enter values into. There is a loop that shows the value associated with the keys depending on a if condition

`inv_dict_celltype` and `buf_dict_celltype` are dictioanries. From the code below i observe that when i try to access both the dictionaries in different scenarios the code doesn't work. The output I get shows the dictionary values present in the first statement I give here, I get all the values in `inv_dect_celltype` but it doesn't proceed with next `if` statement, instead comes out

And the `temp_list` contains the following data :

```
temp_list = {'INV_X20B_NXP7P5PP96PTL_C16', 'INV_X6B_NXP7P5PP96PTL_C16', 
             'INV_X8B_NXP7P5PP96PTL_C16', 'INV_X16B_NXP7P5PP96PTL_C16', 
             'INV_X10B_NXP7P5PP96PTL_C16', 'BUF_X6N_A7P5PP96PTL_C16', 
             'BUF_X20N_A7P5PP96PTL_C16', 'BUF_X8N_A7P5PP96PTL_C16', 
             'BUF_X10N_A7P5PP96PTL_C16', 'BUF_X7N_A7P5PP96PTL_C16', 
              'BUF_X1P3N_A7P5PP96PTS_C18'}

for each_cell in temp_list:    
    if each_cell.startswith('INV_'):    
        print(inv_dict_celltype[each_cell])    
    if each_cell.startswith('BUF_'):            
        print(buf_dict_celltype[each_cell])
```

Comment: FYI, `temp_list` is a set, not a list.

Comment: I can't see any reason why the dictionary access wouldn't work. Add the values of the dictionaries. Also, you should use `elif` since the conditions are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Can you add the other two dictionaries you're using?

Comment: Could you give us a description of exactly what happens when it 'doesn't work'? Does it print anything before it stops?

Comment: what do you mean by *it doesn't proceed with next `if`*?

Comment: Only one of the `if` statements can be true for any particular element of `temp_list`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you want to retrieve from your dictionaries, and how the other two dictionaries look like, but try with the following.

```py
for each_cell in temp_list:
     if each_cell.startswith('INV_'):
          for i in inv_dict_celltype:
               if i == each_cell:
                   print(i) 
     if each_cell.startswith('BUF_'):
          for x in buf_dict_celltype:
               if x == each_cell:
                    print(x)
```